# understanding sql left outer join

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I've got the following tables:

```
Articles:
Nr    Name     Price
1011  DU        10
1012  DA        5
1013  DO        20

Clients
Nr    Name    Street   Zip
123   John     ...      ...
234    Will    ...     ...

Orders
Nr   Client_Nr    Art_Nr    Quantity
1     123          1011       1
2     123          1012       2
3     234          1012       2
4     234          1013       5
```

To know the total sum of orders per customer,
I use the following statement:

```
SELECT Clients.Name, 
    SUM(Orders.Quantity * Article.Price) AS "Total" 
FROM Orders 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Articles 
    ON Orders.Art_Nr = Articles.Nr 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Clients 
    ON Orders.Client_Nr = Clients.Nr 
GROUP BY Clients.Name;
```

Is left outer joins used when there are rows in one table that may not be referenced in the second table.

What is the better way of writing the above query?

Can I do this:

```
SELECT clients.name, SUM(orders.quantity * articles.price)
FROM orders
    INNER JOIN articles ON orders.art_nr = articles.nr
    INNER JOIN clients ON orders.client_nr = clients.nr
GROUP BY clients.name;
```

Comment: You can check this for understanding joins http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: I think it should work. It is not the problem of the joins, it is because mysql (even the newest versions) are very far from the flexibility of an usable SQL server. In your place I used postgresql. Next to that, instead of "nr" I suggest to use "id", it is more common in the db world.

Comment: According to your sample data, you should be using an inner join. You might use a left join if the field Art_nr from Orders was nullable, but this does not make much sense here. I have also tried both SQL queries with the sample data on MySQL. Both queries return the same results! Maybe there is an issue elsewhere.